# ROS Answers SE migration: roslint error

Tags: calibration, kinect, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to perform an extrinsic calibration based on the following tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_extrinsic_cal/Tutorials/Camera%20to%20Target

I have installed all the dependencies outlines and when I try catkin_make before carrying out the steps outlined in the tutorial I get the following errors:

```
...catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package roslint.

  Set roslint_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  roslint.  The file will have one of the following names:

    roslintConfig.cmake
    roslint-config.cmake
```

**And**

```
...CMakeLists.txt:206 (roslint_cpp):
  Unknown CMake command "roslint_cpp".
```

Anybody ever have the same problem or could help in fixing it?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204078/roslint-error/) by [Gurj](https://answers.ros.org/users/21617/gurj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have installed all the dependencies outline(d) [..]

The error simply states that you don't have [roslint](http://wiki.ros.org/roslint) installed.

Could you detail how you checked that you installed all dependencies? `rosdep` should pick up on the dependency, as the [package manifest](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_calibration/blob/a27d7a5d4a8c701cd9ac6b3ac3362baf8b24bd80/industrial_extrinsic_cal/package.xml#L48) for `industrial_extrinsic_cal` does list it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>industrial_extrinsic_cal</name>
  ...
  <build_depend>roslint</build_depend>
  ...
</package>
```

You should be able to install it using `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-roslint`.

For future reference: use

```
rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
```

to check that you have all (build) dependencies installed.

You can use `rosdep install ..` to have `rosdep` install any dependencies that it determines are missing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4